# Mongoid: update_attributes vs update_all

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

In the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/) they don't mention a subtle difference between `Criteria#update_attributes` and `Criteria#update_all`. The latter doesn't update `updated_at` document field.

Is that desired behavior? If so, shouldn't it be reflected in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implied assumption is that you're familiar with ActiveRecord and they're assuming that you're assuming that Mongoid behaves like ActiveRecord (except where it can't). In ActiveRecord, [`update_all` is explicitly documented](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) to not call callbacks:

> **update_all(updates)**
>
> [...] This method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it straight to the database. It does not instantiate the involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations. [...]

Mongoid's `update_all` similarly sends a single `update` operation into MongoDB without calling callbacks.

The Mongoid documentation is (as usual in Ruby) a bit thin on important details so you'll have to get used to making guesses and reading the source of the libraries you're using. Including tests to verify your guesses is also a good idea to avoid unpleasentness during upgrades.

Comment: > c.update_all(resources) throws: NoMethodError: undefined method `update_all' -- is there a modern equivalent?

Comment: @RomanGaufman The [Mongoid docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/6.1/api/Mongoid/Contextual/Mongo.html#update_all-instance_method) suggest that `update_all` should work. What specifically is `c`? Which version of Mongoid?